# Reading elements into a dictionary object using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am using traditional XmlReader to parse a xml document into a dictionary? However i am in search for less complicated method minimum lines of code. I have the following Xml document

```
<Msg>
  <field id="0" value="0100"/>
  <field id="3" value="310000"/>
  <field id="7" value="0101150110"/>  
  <field id="11" value="000002"/>
</Msg>
```

Is it possible to split  the following xml document into a dictionary object with key being the attribute and value being the value of that element?

eg:-
Key = 0 value =0100

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using `XmlReader`, I'd suggest using LINQ to XML, at which point it's really simple:

```
var dictionary = document.Descendants("field")
                         .ToDictionary(x => (int) x.Attribute("id"),
                                       x => (string) x.Attribute("value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = (from element in document.Descendants("field"))
             .ToDictionary(pair => (int)pair.Attribute("id"), 
                           pair => (string)pair.Attribute("value"));
```

Comment: Why would you create a new anonymous type, only to split it up again in a `ToDictionary` call immediately afterwards? See my answer for a simpler approach (IMO).